# Nested Route link_to loop route helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

If I visit this page /articles/1/comments

Why won't this work (views/comments/index.html.erb)

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
<%= link_to "show", article_comment_path(comment)
<% end %>
```

and this will?

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
<%= link_to "show", article_comment_path(@article, comment)
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :articles
  resources :comments
end
```

I would think the route helper would be smart enough to infer I want to use the article in the current context...

Magic is pretty nice except when you spend a lot of time expecting it to be magical and it's not :P

Answer (score 1):

You cannot expect too much. This way you still have the freedom to use an instance variable, a plain parameter. The link_to helper can also be used outside the context of the controller. Furthermore, the list of possible parameters is dynamic. If you give one parameter, it has no way of knowing which you did specify: the article? The comment?

Note that you can just write:

```
link_to "show article", @article
link_to "show comment", [@article, comment]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i think i see what mean. your answer sheds more light on the issue. what it makes me think is that rails is smart not to make an assumption on what route you want. i'd have to look at it more but it does seem like making an assumption that comment = /articles/1/comment/1 is right, just can't imagine how that would break anything. especially given that my routes (see updated).